# Is it true that any haram food that we consume, our Dua's do not get accepted for 40 days?

Tags: dua, food, islamic-basis

Is it true that any haram food that we consume, our Dua's do not get accepted for 40 days?  If so, where is the reference for this and does this include sheesha, smoking and other haram consumables?

Comment: [Read](http://m.askaquestionto.us/question-answer/worship/are-the-prayers-of-a-person-who-got-alcohol-not-accepted). Might be relevant

Comment: This question is sore lacking in either details or research effort.  Why would you even think this is something that would even be referenceable?  What if any effort have you put into finding the answer yourself?

Comment: Also, you should include the actual question in the question body, not leave it only in the title.

Answer (score 2):

The Hadith that mention that eating haram makes your prayer not accepted for 40 days is a fake Hadith according to Hadith scholars.

The Hadith is:

> Narrated Ibn Mas'oud: Whoever eats a bite of Haram food, their prayer is not accepted for 40 days

- Hadith Scholar [Zain Al-Deen Al-Iraqi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abd_al-Rahim_ibn_al-Husain_al-%27Iraqi) judged this hadith as fake in the book تخريج أحاديث الإحياء
- Hadith Scholar [Ibn-Hajar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Hajar_al-Asqalani) judged this hadith as fake in his book لسا الميزان

So that's not true, eating haram doesn't make the prayer not accepted for 40 days. However, that doesn't mean you can eat haram, eating haram is, obviously, forbidden and Allah punishes people who do so.

[Reference.](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/121987)

Comment: Are there any English language resources you could share on this?

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, there is a similar or even the same hadith (tradition) regarding the mentioned matter.

It has been narrated that Prophet Muhammad (blessings of Allah be upon him and his family) said:

> من اکل لقمة حرام لن تقبل له صلوة اربعین لیلة، و لم تستجب له دعوة
>   اربعین صباحا و کل لحم ینبته الحرام فالنار اولی به و ان اللقمة الواحدة
>   تنبت اللحم؛
>
> Whoever eats haram (his morsel is haram), his prayers won’t be
>   accepted (or won’t be valuable) till forty nights and his duas won’t
>   be granted …
>
> بحارالأنوار  ، 63/314 (Bahara al-Anwar)

In regard to the second part of your question which inquired "does this include sheesha, smoking and other haram consumables?" I should point that as far as I searched, I didn't find the same issue exactly as you inquired, but seemingly, mainly it could be related to the foods which you haven't obtained them as a halal food, e.g:

- You sold something more expensive than its real value against the law...
- Your money is mixed by the property of an orphan
- you stole.. and so forth.

Of course it could be considered from another aspect. E.g  according to this significant point that the sin could be counted as a reason which will be the obstacle of duas granting, therefore the mentioned items which you said would be considered as the obstacle of dua granting. Because according to an Islamic rule  (الکافي، ج 2،‌ ص 296 (Al-Kafi)) whatever has disadvantage for the body could be counted as a haram act.

---

**Source(s):**

http://www.hawzah.net/fa/book/bookview/45325/34735

http://old.ido.ir/a.aspx?a=1391080804

[http://www.almazaheri.ir](http://www.almazaheri.ir/farsi/Index.aspx?TabID=0604&SectionNum=2110&ChapterNum=608&ChapterName=%D9%81%D8%B5%D9%84%20%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%B2%D8%AF%D9%87%D9%85:%20%D8%AF%D8%B9%D8%A7%20%D9%88%20%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%82%D8%B7%D8%A7%D8%B9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87&BookNum=127&BookName=%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%B1%20%D9%88%20%D8%B3%D9%84%D9%88%DA%A9%20-%20%D9%85%D9%82%D8%AF%D9%85%D9%87&CompileNum=40&CompileName=%D8%B9%D8%B1%D9%81%D8%A7%D9%86)

Comment: Also, plz do some research if the Hadith which you've used are authentic or not.

Answer (score -1):

Is it true that any haram food that we consume, our Dua's do not get accepted for 40 days?
up vote

TRUE
 Jaabir (Radiyallaahu Anhu) narrates that Rasulullah (Sallallaahu Alaihi Wa Sallam) said, "No meat (i.e. person) that was nourished with haraam will enter paradise. Every meat (i.e. person) that was nourished with haraam is more deserving of the Fire." (Musnad Ahmad, Daarami, Baihaqi; Mishkaatul Masaabih pg. 242, Qadeemi)

Comment: Evidences are not selfexplanatory!